# Angular $interval only firing once

Tags: angularjs, setinterval, intervals

I don't get it. I only see "interval" logged once to the window's console with this code:

```
$interval(function () { console.log("interval"); }, 1000, 0, false);
```

What am I missing?

Edit: I have Chrome debugger options set to put a timestamp on every console line. So yeah, it only shows once. :/

Comment: Can't tell from your code, are there any angular errors in the console?  The console collapses consecutive logs that are the same, do you see a number by the text?  Can you manually log something else?

Comment: That's the only thing I can figure--there's some error happening. But I have debugger set to break on exceptions, caught or uncaught. :(

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or plnkr